# python zip contains whole structure not the file that is desired

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, zip

I want to zip a file in python and below is the code

```
output_file = 'D:/users/aaa.zip'
input_file = 'D:/users/aaa.txt'
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(output_file, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zf.write(output_file, arcname=input_file)
zf.close()
print('>> End zipFile...')
```

I am trying to zip the file but when I open to extract the created zip I have `users` folder and then `aaa.txt`. Is there a way that I have aaa.txt directly?

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
zf.write(outputFilename, filePath)
```